# iPhone - Synthesize and ivar use from outside the class?

Tags: iphone, properties, instance-variables, accessor, synthesizer

I've read many things about the @synthesize call. About its use, ...
So I have made a test, and its result gives me a strange feeling.
Let me explain...

## Lets write in an object .h

```
@interface AnObject : NSObject {
    NSString* aaTest;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* bbTest;

-(void)log;
```

Then in its .m

```
@synthesize bbTest = aaTest;

-(void)log {
    NSLog(@"Inside var : %@", aaTest);
    NSLog(@"Inside property : %@", self.bbTest);
}
```

## In **another** .m, let's write :

```
#import "AnObject.h"
```

then into one method :

```
    AnObject* testCtrl = [[AnObject alloc] init];
    testCtrl.bbTest = @"Some string";
    NSLog(@"Outside property : %@", testCtrl.bbTest);
    [testCtrl log];
```

We are ok that here, including only the .h, the synthesize call is not known from the other object. Looking at the Log, it gives :

```
Outside property : Some string
Inside var : Some string
Inside property : Some string
```

So... Isn't that strange ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your synthesize call, you assign bbtest to aaTest (note the capital T).  That's not the same as aatest

Comment: Ooops, you're right. Could you remove your answer so I can delete this useless post please ?